# Can I set an Overlay Image for a QstandardItem that has been bound in a QListview?

Tags: qt, qt4, overlay, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

The application on which I'm working on has QStandardItems laid in QListView. I want to set a transparent image on the QStandardItem which is bound in a listview. How can a set an Overlay image on the QListView item ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom delegate. Ovverride paint() method in next way:

1) QItemDelegate::paint( default args... );

2) p->drawPixmap( your overlay image )